# A second operation was started on this context Even though Dbcontext was declared trainsent

Tags: entity-framework, blazor, identity

This error is produce somethings not always and when database on server if database on machine local there is no problem
i found it in sql database and in mysql database
the DbContext is registred as ServiceLifetime.Transient but problem still appear whene database on server

the problem procude when i try to get role for user in  `user.RoleNames = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);`

```
 protected async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Load()
        {
            var securityGetUserByIdResult = await Security.GetUserById($"{Id}");
            user = securityGetUserByIdResult;

            var securityGetRolesResult = await Security.GetRoles();
            roles = securityGetRolesResult;
        }
```

then i call GetUserById

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserById(string id)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            
            if (user != null)
            {
                context.Entry(user).Reload();
                user.RoleNames = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(user);
        }
```

i tried multiple soulution like semaphoreSlim nothing solve problem

Comment: A DbContext should be registered as Scoped, not Transient. The details depend on Blazor Server or Blazor Wasm.

Comment: If the call is made inside OnInitializedAsync it might trigger twice, even before the previous operation finished. The transient scope is only once per component. This have caused InvalidOperationException with second operation for me in the past.